# Can we convert 'possible bipartite' question to 'max flow' question

Tags: bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path

Ok, I am in dangerous waters :)

I just began looking into popular graph interview questions and came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ACfAqs8mm0&t=1021s) classical one

```
to find if we can divide all the incompatible persons into 2 different SETs
```

Instead of just cramming up the solution, I really wanted to understand/learn about graphs so began searching for similar questions theories.

And now I am confused a bit :(

There was one [question](https://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Ewallingf/teaching/cs3530/sessions/session24.html) about finding a seating arrangement around a round table between incompatible CEOs. There it suggests creating a graph of compatible CEOs instead, and find a `Hamiltonian Cycle`. I could understand that since it's a round table, the cycle would give the solution.

Then, there is another similar [question](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/%7Edmarino/progcontests/modules/netflow2/NetFlow-Apps.pdf) about creating a `maximum compatible group` from kids in 2 separate classes, some of whom hate each other. There it suggests using `max flow` to get the max number of pairs. Similarly the 'Grand Dinner' problem explained there

Then there is the original question, where I started from :) Here, what I think they are trying to do is given a condition `(1 hates 2)`, they actually create 2 edges 1-->2 and 2-->1 and the solution suggests checking that all the cycles are even in length using the `2 color technique`

I am wondering if this is a totally separate category of question or it can be converted to `max flow` question ? Will `Hamiltonian path` also come into picture ?

Or am I getting it all wrong :( and mixing `bipartite/Hamiltonian/max flow`

Comment: As you mention toward the end, the bipartite graph problem is equivalent to asking for a 2-coloring of a graph.  I'm  not sure of the rest of your Question.  A bipartite graph may or may not have a Hamiltonian path, and a graph which has a Hamiltonian path may or may not be bipartite.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. The rest of the question is basically `can we convert 'possible bipartition' to 'max flow' question ?`

Comment: Max flow problems generally have a single source and single sink. This is easier than that. Just pick a vertex and color it red. Then do a breadth first search coloring the adjacent vertices the opposite color. You will either complete the search, in which case the graph is bipartite, or you will find an adjacent vertex that has already been visited with the same color.

Comment: @JohnDouma, Yes, that is exactly what the video suggests. But my question is, can this problem be represented as 'max flow' problem. Like the `Grand Dinner` from the link I posted above where there are Nm teams each having Ti members and Si chairs. And it is desired that 2 people from the same team should not be at the same table. That question was converted to `max flow` by introducing source and sink. I thought that this question could also be solved the same way but I could not figure out if that is possible.

Comment: @mittal That seems very kludgy to me. The Max Flow algorithms will tell you the maximum capacity of a network. How will knowing the maximum flow through an edge tell you if it connects two vertices in opposite sets? You mentioned that you were looking at graph interview questions. I can tell you, as someone with a lot of experience as a technical interviewer, if a candidate tried to determine if a graph was bipartite by using Max Flow, I would consider that a smell.

Comment: `I can tell you, as someone with a lot of experience as a technical interviewer, if a candidate tried to determine if a graph was bipartite by using Max Flow, I would consider that a smell` Thanks John. As I said, I am bit confused. Now that I think about it, I am trying to 'test bipartiteness' with 'max flow', which is kinda wrong. If it were a bipartite set, max flow could have give me the maximum matching. But give any graph, max flow won't be able to test for bipartiteness

Comment: @mittal Max Flow is equivalent to Min Cut but members of the cut can have connections between them, violating the bipartite condition. Try to code the standard algorithm. It's not that hard and you will be happy with your code when you see how few lines it actually takes.

Comment: @JohnDouma, many thanks for clearing up my doubt. By changing 'max flow' to 'min cut', and then adding the statement `but members of the cut can have connections between them, violating the bipartite condition.` has put things in perspective. Please make that statement as the answer and I'll be more than happy to accept :)

Comment: @mittal I appreciate that but this question is really more suited for stackoverflow so, as long as you are good, so am I.

Comment: The reason I posted it here was to understand the mathematical aspect of it and not just the algorithm to solve that particular question. Thanks for your time